# "BasicNameValuePair" Parameters not passing into PHP from Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, parameters

I get the "No Items found" toast on the ListActivity.

Note:  When I change the PHP code to "Select * from items", the entire table shows up.  But when I try to filter it with the param/cat_id value in Android/Java, I get a blank

Here is code, first:  php

```
 <?php
      $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE cat_id = ' ".$_REQUEST['cat_id']." '");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    $output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
 ?>
```

(I have confirmed that "cat_id", the value I am passing into the below activity through a bundle is what it needs to be.)

Android/Java:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    cat_id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("category_id");
    items = new ArrayList<String>();

    new task().execute();

}

 class task extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url_select = "http://www.---.com/---/items.php";

        param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category_id", cat_id));

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            // read content
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {

         //

        }
```

and farther below

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

        String item;
        try {
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                item = json_data.getString("item");

                items.add(item);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Items Found",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I get the "No Items found" toast on the ListActivity.

Note:  When I change the PHP code to "Select * from items", the entire table shows up.  But when I try to filter it with the param/cat_id value in Android/Java, I get a blank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the Java code you write

```
 param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category_id", cat_id));
```

but on the PHP code you write

```
$_REQUEST['cat_id']
```

you should change it to

```
$_REQUEST['category_id']
```